# Using the same table view cell in multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I have a custom table view cell class, which I use in several view controller's table views. I am adding a feature that gives the user the ability to delete a table view cell and I'd like to remove the cell from the table view when they do so.

Using a delegate is one way to achieve this, so that when the user deletes the table view cell, the table view cell class informs the view controller, through the delegate, that it was deleted and to remove it from the table view. However, this would mean I'd have to do this for each of my several view controllers, which I don't want to do.

So my question is, how can I implement this in such a way that I only have to write the code to remove the table view cell from the table view once?

Comment: write baseTableView class ... inherit your tableview from that class ... and do that in that class

Comment: Tableview cell is shown based on your data source array, So You have to inform the view controller has Datasource to remove data and cell from the table view, there is no other way to do this automatically. By informing each viewcontroller using this cell is not wrong way, so chill :)

Comment: Create a global array as a datasource for your tableviews and when cell is deleted update that array and reload your tableviews.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the UITableView. Create a protocol like:

```
protocol customTableViewDelegate {
  func deleteTableViewCell()
}
```

Then give the subclassed UITableView a variable of this type:

```
var removeCellDelegate: customTableViewDelegate?
```

And then instead of adding a normal UITableView to your view controller, add the custom one and set the removeCellDelegate to the view controller. Then implement the function to do whatever you want.